# When to contact recruiter about written offer?

Tags: job-offer

Last Friday I was extended a verbal offer for an entry-level job at a large corporation. In the phone call, the recruiter and I discussed salary, benefits and my start date. They also mentioned that I would need to complete a formal employment application, with all my education and employment history, before I could receive a written offer.

Shortly after the phone call, I was given an email that re-iterated what the recruiter had said, and included a statement about the offer being contingent on a background check, which I consented to in the formal application and completed the application over the weekend.

My question is....is it 'normal' for application processing to take this long? I'm considering contacting the recruiter sometime at the beginning of next week to touch base, though I'm not sure. The background check and drug test don't happen until I sign the written offer, so essentially it's just a matter of waiting for that.

Answer (score 1):

They will take however long they take. -- processing time is very variable from company to company and may depend on who's on vacation next week. You can contact them and ask when you should expect to get that letter.

Reminder: until the hardcopy arrives, don't assume you definitely have that job. A phone offer may not be worth the paper it's printed on.